# Is there a way to output horizontally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, console

I am trying to output this on console but it is not working as I want.

```
what I want is:

1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 <---I WANT IT LIKE THIS
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

```
And not:

1
2
3
4
5
1
2 <-- I DONT WANT IT LIKE THIS
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Please is there a way to achieve it purely on javascript without HTML with the code below?

```
let n = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        console.log(j + " ");
        if (j = 5) {
            console.log("\n");
        } else continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note, `if (j = 5)` is invalid. It should be `if (j == 5)` or `if (j === 5)`

Comment: use `<br/>` tag

Comment: @j08691 no it is not. This is perfectly valid code. It's just highly discouraged because of the possible misunderstanding. Did you really mean to assign a value or did you mean to write a comparison? Like in this sample.

Comment: @Thomas Why would he be assigning a value inside an `if`? Of course it's a comparison and should be `==` or `===`. The OP is testing when to insert a break.

Comment: `console.log` normally prints a whole line. If you want precise control over the output, use an output stream or make the result a single string value (to return to the caller, instead of printing it yourself).

Comment: @j08691 I totally agree with you last comment, but your first comment states that this syntax is invalid, and that is simply is not correct.

Comment: @Thomas Ok technically it's a logic error and not a syntax error. I actually didn't say it was a syntax error in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary string to add your i values and log it in the end of each outer loop

```js
let n = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    var temp = "";
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        temp=temp+" "+j;
     }
     console.log(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and spread the values of it.

BTW, please declare **all** variables, because if not, these variables are global and could lead to crazy results if taken in some loops in different functions.

```js
let length = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    console.log(...Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let n = 5;
let line = "";
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    line = "";
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        line += " " + j;
    }
    console.log(line);
}
```

Comment: Using your format, add an additional variable [in the example above: line] and clear it immediately after the 1st loop, it stores each line entry and log it at the end of the line-loop.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading Sunil Lama's answer:

```
var n = 5;
var finaloutput = "";
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    var temp = "";
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
       temp=temp+" "+j;
    }
    finaloutput +=  temp + "\r\n";
}
console.log(finaloutput);
```

Result in console:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5    
 1 2 3 4 5    
 1 2 3 4 5    
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: What about this is an "upgrade"?

Comment: Instead of just writing it to console 5 times, at the end I added output to "finaloutput" to get desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out something that other answers don't mention: new line characters.

You can form your string beforehand using new lines where necessary, then `console.log()` once.

```js
let string = ''
let columns = 5
let rows = 5
for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
    string += j + ' '
  }
  string += '\n'
}
console.log(string)
```